# Excel VBA Delete row if three values are met, or if one of the three values is blank

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

this is Chris here! Earlier this week I posted a question regarding code that was meant to delete a row if three cells in different columns (same row) met a certain text value criteria. In this case, the text value was "PURGE" for all three cells, non-case sensitive.

The method was to search a column (in this case D), find the first value that met the search term, then offset to the next specified column to verify the existence of the following value criteria to be met.

My question today is, how do I specify that one of the criteria that I will accept is a blank value? I would like to modify my code to, for example, search Column 4(D) for "PURGE" and if Column 5(E) is blank(nothing) and Column 6(F) says "PURGE" then delete that row.

I will post the code which a good fellow named Tom helped me out with.

Also, I will be copying and moving code around to meet conditions in which the search term will be different. I may also want to edit the code to accept more than one blank cell value as criteria for deletion.

Let me know if there's any way I can make my question more clear, or if there's already a post with the answer I need that I couldn't find!

Much appreciated all, your time here means more than I can write in text!
-Chris

This is what I've got:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRows()
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim strPath As String, strFile As String, strFind As String, firstAddress As 
String
Dim x As Range, y As Range, z As Range
Dim DelRng As Range


'searches directory for any and all excel files
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If .Show Then
        strPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        MsgBox "No folder selected!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With

If Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    strPath = strPath & "\"
End If

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Stops xlsm files on Open event
    .EnableEvents = False
    ' uncomment to hide any deletion message boxes
    ' .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")

'end file finding and such

Do While Len(strFile) > 0

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile, AddToMRU:=False)

    For Each wsh In wbk.Worksheets

        'supposed to search column d, offset column +1 in same row,
        'then do same for a third row.
        'if all three cells contain "PURGE" then delete cell

        With wsh.Columns(4)
            Set x = .Find("PURGE", Lookat:=xlPart)
            If Not x Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = x.Address
                Do
                    If InStr(1, x.Offset(0, 1), "purge", vbTextCompare) > 0 And InStr(1, x.Offset(0, 2), "purge", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        If DelRng Is Nothing Then
                            Set DelRng = x
                        Else
                            Set DelRng = Union(DelRng, x)
                        End If
                    End If
                    Set x = .FindNext(x)
                Loop While Not x Is Nothing And x.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
        End With
    Next wsh
    If Not DelRng Is Nothing Then DelRng.EntireRow.Delete

    wbk.Close SaveChanges:=True
    strFile = Dir()
Loop

With Application
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why aren't you filtering each of the three columns for *purge* or blank?

Comment: You would just use an empty string `""` instead of `"purge"` for the cell you want.

Comment: I may not be educated on the methods of filtering available, or the exact effect.
I chose offset because it is important that the values I am searching be explicity related to data which I have stored in other columns of the same row. I imagine that if I filter, I might get mixed results in which I am either not finding or am deleting bits of each row instead of locking on to exact criteria. In this I believe I am uneducated.
As far as using "" to substitute for "PURGE", I tried doing that and I got no effect. I am not sure what's up.

Comment: Here is a link with a folder that has my file in it. The macro-enabled workbook is outdated now, but the macro-free workbook is the exact same kind of file I need to be cleaning.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz4rZ9ZqoU0tU3M3bzQydTlvbzA

Thanks again guys *thumbs up*

Comment: The actual row deletion (e.g. `DelRng.EntireRow.Delete`) seems out of place. Shouldn't it be inside the worksheet loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a two criteria .AutoFilter with xlOr seems a more efficient method.

```
For Each wsh In wbk.Worksheets
    With wsh
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="*purge*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=""
            .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="*purge*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=""
            .AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="*purge*", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:=""
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete
                End If
            End With
        End With
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
Next wsh
```

Comment: I like this a lot, so I am going to put this little bit in there. Is there a way you would suggest sliding this into my code? I will leave the workbook and directory selection code, but should I get rid of my Len(strFile) code? And should I Dim Criteria 1, 2 (and maybe 3 if I want to add it)?

Comment: I will be eliminating my string search code by the way, all of the offsets and text searching.

As of now with this bit of filter code I am getting an "application-defined" or "object-defined" error

Comment: This should replace the code you have inside your `For Each wsh In wbk.Worksheets` loop. 2. There is no Criterias3 and that would be another question (one that I have answered in another earlier question).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Doing as you said, I swapped out the code and it is working beautifully!

Much appreciation for your help, it is a pleasure!